# Hibernate deep nested collection restriction not working

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql

I have a quite large and messy datastructure of a questionnaire, which has resulted in a long HQL

```
select s from Session s join s.questionnaire q join q.categories c join c.questions q2 join q2.answers a where a.session.id=:id2 and s.id=:id
```

I think that this HQL looks reasonable and the resulting sql as well

```
select session0_.id as id1_9_, session0_.name as name2_9_, session0_.position as position3_9_, session0_.questionnaire as question4_9_ from session session0_ inner join questionnaire questionna1_ on session0_.questionnaire=questionna1_.id inner join category categories2_ on questionna1_.id=categories2_.parent_questionnaire inner join question questions3_ on categories2_.id=questions3_.parent_category inner join answer answers4_ on questions3_.id=answers4_.question where answers4_.session=? and session0_.id=?
```

...even if it is quite large

But for some reason it is completely ignoring the `answer` restriction.
When checking in the debugger I can see 4 different answers for 4 different sessions.
How is this possible?

**Edit**

OK, this is really interesting...

```
select s from Session s join s.questionnaire q join q.categories c where c.name=:name and s.id=:id
```

this is also not working and the categories are not filtered, so I am assuming the mapping between Session and Questionnaire is wrong?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "session")
@Cacheable
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(region = "session", usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Session implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "questionnaire")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private Questionnaire questionnaire;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "questionnaire")
@Cacheable
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(region = "questionnaire", usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Questionnaire implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;
}
```

... changing to this doesn't work

```
select q from Questionnaire q join q.categories c where c.name=:name
```

so I am completely lost

Comment: *When checking in the debugger I can see 4 different answers for 4 different sessions* and whats wrong with that? What is the expected outcome?

Comment: Well since I am checking `where a.session.id=:id2` I assumed that all answers returned would have the same session set. And in this case I expect exactly one answer